Android Jetpack Compose How to show tooltip after simple click
I saw a an answer on how to implement the new tooltipBox (Android Compose - Alternative to PlainTooltipBox (deprecated))
But now it only works after a LongPress on my Icon, how can I change this.
is it possible to show after one click and dismiss after clicking again or somewhere else ?
So far this is my Code:
TooltipBox(
                        positionProvider = TooltipDefaults.rememberRichTooltipPositionProvider(),
                        tooltip = { RichTooltip(title = { Text("Smart Cycle") }, text = { Text("If enabled, the cycle will automatically be detected, starting with the highest paycheck") })},
                        state = rememberTooltipState()) {
                            IconButton(onClick = {  }) {
                                Icon(Icons.Default.Info, contentDescription = "info")
                            }
                    }

I thought maybe its possible to change that in the state

You can manually show the tooltip by calling TooltipState::show as you can see in RichTooltipWithManualInvocationSample:
val tooltipState = rememberTooltipState()
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

TooltipBox(
    state = tooltipState,
    ...
) {
    IconButton(
        onClick = { scope.launch { tooltipState.show() } }
    ) { ... }
}


in order to achieve that behaviour you need to have access to the too TooltipState so instead of directly passing it to the TooltipBox assign it to a variable and then pass that state variable to TooltipBox so you can use it in the  IconButton onClick lambda and also another thing you need to consider is that state.show() is suspend function which means you can only use it in a couroutine or another suspend fun so we are going to create a variable scope=
rememberCoroutinescope().
here is a working implementation:
  val state = rememberTooltipState()
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
                TooltipBox(
                    positionProvider = TooltipDefaults.rememberRichTooltipPositionProvider(),
                    tooltip = {
                        RichTooltip(
                            title = { Text("Smart Cycle") },
                            text = { Text("If enabled, the cycle will automatically be detected, starting with the highest paycheck") })
                    },
                    state = state
                ) {

                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        scope.launch {
                            state.show(MutatePriority.Default)
                        }
                    }
                    ) {
                        Icon(Icons.Default.Info, contentDescription = "info")
                    }

                }

